SwiftUI using computed property in ForEach statement
I have the following code in my SwiftUI view:
  @Binding var editorVM:EditorViewModel //<--- Is an @Observable class

   var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
            .frame(width:25)
        
        ForEach(visualLayerItems, id: \.id) { item in //<-- this line gives build errors
            ItemView(item)
        }
       
        Spacer()
            .frame(width: 25)
    }
    .padding()
}


  var visualLayerItems:[VisualLayerItem] {
    var items:[VisualLayerItem] = []
    
    if let timelineModel = editorVM.timelineModel, let layerItems = timelineModel.visualLayerItems(inLayer: 0) {
        return layerItems
    }
   
    return items
 }

But I get build error :
  Cannot convert value of type '[VisualLayerItem]' to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'

VisualLayerItem is a class that confirms to Identifiable. I understand I am using a computed property and it looks like ForEach is having trouble with computed property and it probably requires @State variable for the array. I can create an array and store it in a @State variable, but I suspect if I make any changes in my timelineModel  (stored in EditorViewModel which is @Observable), those changes would not be automatically propagated to the view. What is the right approach here?

It is a typo somewhere

In SwiftUI the View structs are the view model and you should pass in only the properties they need not whole objects. Use let for read only, @Binding var for read/write.

try using var editorVM: EditorViewModel never @Binding for whole of @Observable. You can use @Bindable but it is not required by your code. Also use ForEach(visualLayerItems) since as you say VisualLayerItem conforms to Identifiable. Also try making VisualLayerItem a struct.

Have a look at this Apple link Managing model data in your app, for how to manage data in your app. The examples show clearly how you should pass the whole @Observable to views.

I think his example is view data not model data but it’s kinda hard to tell maybe he should clarify and remove “viewmodel” if the editor it is a model object.

Why do you need a binding here? You're not modifying it anywhere

@BrandonStillitano I need a binding of item in ItemView, even though I don't modify it in ItemView but I need ItemView to reload on any changes in item.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks for the answer. I used @Bindable, and removed @Binding in ItemView for item. It works, but I wonder how will ItemView respond to changes made in item?

it's all done for you, it is observed by the view. It will work.
